# fast way to calculate mean with large dataset

Tags: r, performance, aggregate, mean

I have very large dataset like following:

```
myd <- data.frame (id = paste("id_",rep(1:500000, each = 3), sep=""),
      yvar= rep(1:500000, each= 3), xvar= rep(1:500000, each= 3))
```

I would like to calculate mean for ids. I am trying the following it is taking **long time**.

```
myd1 <- aggregate(myd, list(myd$id), mean)
```

Any quicker to do this ?

Comment: Did you read the answer below? It's a bajillion times faster than yours (which has a typo) on my computer. I guess yours should be `aggregate(myd[, -1], list(myd$id), mean)`

Comment: thank you for reading the question carefully and answered it.

Comment: For a comprehensive speed comparison, see Ari Friedman's answer to the "Average data by group" question linked above.

Comment: thank you, for pointing the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(myd)
myd[,.(mean(yvar),mean(xvar)),by=(id)]
```

Performance comparison as follows:

```
system.time(myd1 <-aggregate(myd[, -1], list(myd$id), mean)) 
user  system elapsed 
19.56    0.08   19.72 

system.time(mydt1<-mydt[,.(mean(yvar),mean(xvar)),by=(id)])
user  system elapsed 
0.07    0.00    0.06
```